# WPF application with MS Access database as a data source

Tags: wpf, database, ms-access, visual-studio-2010, datasource

I have a Microsoft Access 2010 database(*). Now, using Visual Studio 2010, I want to create a WPF application and add the database as a data source. The app will have a window with a frame that provides navigation through pages. No problem so far. But:

-What is the right way to set up the database in this scenario? Tables only? Or must *everything* go via queries? (VS2010 talks about views which I assume (?) are queries)

-Database data must be updatable and records can be added. Some relationships go through link tables (many-to-many) and there are nullable foreign key relationships. Must I take manual steps to make it work?

-While adding the data source VS2010 created an xsd from my Access database. I think the xsd might need further tweaking for the application to work the right way. What if I change my Access database design, I'd have to regenerate the xsd again as well. Is this right, and is it the way it is usually done? OR, should I let the original Access database go and give the application the capability to create new empty databases?

-How do you provide controls in a page to step through the records in a table? Is there a special database control?

-What is the way (WPF class?) to load records into the data context that displays in a page? (At this level it probably does not matter what type of data source it is.)

(*) A single user desktop database

Comment: I'd highly recommend moving away from access, as the tooling support for a SQL database is a lot better; and will allow you to have a lot of code generated assuming you're developing a straightforward CRUD app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the exact answer to the question. But an alternative.

Is this a single-user database?

You can try this better and highly efficient combination:

- [SQLITE](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html) (DataBase)
- [DBLINQ](http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/) ([ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping))
- [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx)(a .NET framework component for querying the db)

You should also take a look at [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx), [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163299.aspx) and DataGrid in [WPF toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/).

Comment: The answer to question of the form "how do I do X" is not "switch from X to Y." I'm adding my own downvote. The only way you can legitimately evade answering the question by recommending a switch is if you explain why switching is the best solution.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: I know this is a "how do I this" kind of question. That's why I've clearly written it is an alternative since giving the solution to this question may lead the QA to stick to access db. Regarding the explanation for recommendation, I think I've provided enough links in my answer. Further, a hint is enough for the QA to browse through the web rather than an entire list of advantages and disadvantages. This is proved by the comments of the QA to my answer.